# Prove the limit..

Tags: real-analysis

$\varinjlim \sqrt{n^2+1}-n=0$.

I need to prove that this converges to 0.

Usung the definition of a sequence helps for the normal problems but for this I believe the triangle inequality is used at some point....

I let $S_n=\varinjlim \sqrt{n^2+1}-n$

Then $|S_n -S|<\epsilon \rightarrow |\varinjlim \sqrt{n^2+1}-n-0|<\epsilon$.

I get to $n^2+1<(\epsilon+n)(\epsilon+n)$ and I'm stuck..

By the definition I'm trying to find $n>N$....

How can I solve this by contradiction? ( since the above lead me nowhere)

Comment: Do you need to prove this using the definition of limits?

Comment: The definition of a sequence when it converges...and the limit does take part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

$$0 < \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{1} = \frac{(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} < \frac{1}{2n}$$

and then prove that the transformed sequence converges to zero.

Comment: Where did $1/2n$ come from?.?

Comment: Clearly, $\sqrt{n^2+1}>n$, so $\sqrt{n^2+1}+n>2n$, and then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}<\frac{1}{2n}$